# Htaccess rules for dynamic sub domain conflicting for index file

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting, subdomain

Here is my htaccess file

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# For Accessing Page http://www.domain.com/news/news-details.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/news-details.php$  news.php [QSA,NC,L]


# For www.domain.com it should go to the index page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [NC,L]
```

when i type http://www.domain.com/news/news-details.php in the browser it takes me to the index.php page rather than news.php. WHY?

EDIT:
Check these rule

```
# For www.domain.com it should go to my-index.php page
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ my-index.php [NC,L]


# For Page URL http://www.domain.com/news/news-details.php
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/news\-details\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ my-news.php [NC,QSA,L]
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# For Page URL http://www.domain.com/news/news-details.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/news-details\.php$ /my-news.php [NC,QSA,L]

# For Accessing Division Page http://user1.domain.com/news/news-details.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST) !^www\.
RewriteRule ^news/news-details\.php$ /my-news.php?user=%1 [QSA,NC,L]

# For Accessing Users Page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /users.php?user=%1 [L]

# For www.domain.com it should go to my-index.php page
# (but only if requested resource is not real file)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-index.php [L]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't the name of the file in the path.

```
RewriteRule ^news/news-details.php$  news.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

here you have the file "news.php" and in the path you have "news".
try another word than news in the path or another name for the file.

for example:

```
RewriteRule ^news/news-details.php$  news_main.php [QSA,NC,L]
```

Comment: I have that file already different. its name is not news.php. Still the index rule is firing and conflicting with the news file