# htaccess confilcting rules for two different files

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

Here are the conflicting rules

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

# For www.domain.com it should go to my-index.php page
#
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ my-index.php [NC,L]

# For Accessing Division Page http://user1.domain.com/news/news-details.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST) !^www\.
RewriteRule ^news/news-details.php$  my-news.php?user=%1 [QSA,NC,L]

# For Page URL http://www.domain.com/news/news-details.php
#
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/news/news\-details\.php [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ my-news.php [NC,QSA,L]

# For Accessing Users Page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /users.php?user=%1 [L]
```

The call for the news page and the index page both goes to the index page. i dont know why?

Comment: Really -- you should show your whole .htaccess content .. not just 2 rules from it. Right now it feels like a game: "Guess What, Guess Why".

Comment: I have edited the post see the whole file now.

Comment: By "index page" you mean `my-index.php` ?

Comment: same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7500829/htaccess-rules-for-dynamic-sub-domain-conflicting-for-index-file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. **The order of rules is important** -- right now both of those mentioned URLs will be served by the first rule which will rewrite them to `my-index.php`.
2. **Your first rule (for `my-index.php`) is too broad** -- even if you place it in correct order it will still rewrite it to the `my-index.php` page -- as you matching everything using `.*` pattern.

Considering the above try these rules:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On

# For Page URL http://www.domain.com/news/news-details.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.domain\.com$  [NC]
RewriteRule ^news/news-details\.php$ /my-news.php [NC,QSA,L]

# For Accessing Division Page http://user1.domain.com/news/news-details.php
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.domain\.com [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST) !^www\.
RewriteRule ^news/news-details\.php$ /my-news.php?user=%1 [QSA,NC,L]

# For Accessing Users Page
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)\.domain\.com$
RewriteRule ^$ /users.php?user=%1 [L]

# For www.domain.com it should go to my-index.php page
# (but only if requested resource is not real file)
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /my-index.php [L]
```

**What I did:**

- rearranged rules: moved `my-index.php` one to the bottom;
- added a condition to not to rewrite requests to existing files (otherwise `my-news.php` will be rewritten as well).

These rules may still require some tweaking -- I do not know what kind of website logic you have there.